# Build tools for Tesseract Training on Windows 10

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

On the Tesseract Github page for training, there is mentioned to install These two additional libraries. where can we find these files for Windows 10:

```
 libpango1.0-dev

 libcairo2-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows [training tools requires](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-project-dependencies) a lot of external libraries that are not common on Windows. Best way is to use [cppan build](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#building-for-x64-platform) or its successor [sw](https://software-network.org) that take care about them.

Answer (score 0):

You Can find it here

```
https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-amd64/libpango1.0-dev_1.42.4-6_amd64.deb.html
```

or try this

```
  https://www.cairographics.org/download/
```